# Trying to run oprofile on ubuntu kernel but cannot find vmlinux file

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, profile

I am trying to run oprofile on my ubuntu host but cannot find the vmlinux file. The set up sfor oprofile needs this file:

As given here : http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.html#getting-started

```
opcontrol --vmlinux=/boot/vmlinux-`uname -r`
```

What should I do so that I can profile the ubuntu kernel.

I am using 2.6.32-34-generic-pae (uname -r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Ubuntu & variants, it's named **vmlinuz**. So your command line for oprofile becomes :

```
opcontrol --vmlinux=/boot/vmlinuz-`uname -r
```

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://superuser.com/questions/62575/where-is-vmlinux-on-my-ubuntu-installation/757739#757739) may help. I copy pasted my solution here again for your convenience.

you can download source and compile your own using the following command:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux-image-$(uname -r)
cd linux-2.6.32/
fakeroot make -f debian/rules binary-generic skipdbg=false
```

or you can download the ddeb package [here](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) and install it by `sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-60-virtual-dbgsym_3.2.0-60.91_amd64.ddeb`